# Search for specific text within a text string using grep or awk

Tags: ubuntu, awk, grep, get, pipe

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"152450"?callback=callbackname`

Please click to see
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOTyr.png)

How would I use `grep` or `awk -F,` to display the highlighted text?

I've tried with `GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"152450"?callback=callbackname | awk -F, '{ print $43$44$45$46 }'`

This will return the profile text, although if I change the Discogs id "number in quotes" to `1` for example, i'm not able to return the same data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"310226"?callback=callbackname |   awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }  {for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I ~ "profile") {print $(I+1)};'}`

with help from Farhad

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
cat file |  awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }  {for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I ~ "profile") {print $(I+1)};'}
```

Comment: `GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"1"?callback=callbackname |   awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }  {for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I ~ "profile") {print $(I+1)};'}`

returned the following string ` "", "urls"`

Comment: Check the output of GET https://api.discogs.com/artists/"1"?callback=callbackname

Comment: @IanArman as the text you provided by link i check the output and the output of command was  as you expect.

Comment: try this


`https://api.discogs.com/artists/310226?callback=callbackname`

Comment: "English actress, b.9 November 1955, Guernsey. Best known for her child role of Jane Banks in Mary Poppins (1964).\r\nShe's the daughter of [a=Roy Dotrice].", "urls"

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":" }  {for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I ~ "profile") {print $(I+1)};}'